# C# How do I write to each part of my array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to write a different 'if' statement for each part of my array. For example an if statement for the NHS number, date of birth, title, etc...
They will all have different 'if' statements.

How do I write a separate if statement for all of them?

This is part of a system that will check the validity of the fields.

I have tried:

```
string[] NHSarray = new string[0];
```

I think this syntax is along the right lines of what I need to do, I just can't figure it out.

```
List<int> NHSnumber = new List<int>();
List<int> DateOfBirth = new List<int>();
List<int> Title = new List<int>();
List<int> GivenName = new List<int>();
List<int> Surname = new List<int>();
List<int> Gender = new List<int>();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\wy6282\Desktop\VS\nhsBatchChecker\Patients.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //split the line
        string[] parts = line.Split(new[] { "Error" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        //get valid integers
        NHSnumber.Add(GetInt(parts[0].Split(' ', '\'')));
        DateOfBirth.Add(GetInt(parts[1].Split(' ', '\'')));
        Title.Add(GetInt(parts[2].Split(' ', '\'')));
        GivenName.Add(GetInt(parts[3].Split(' ', '\'')));
        Surname.Add(GetInt(parts[4].Split(' ', '\'')));
        Gender.Add(GetInt(parts[5].Split(' ', '\'')));
    }
}
```

Comment: What `if` statement are you trying to write?  This is really unclear.

Comment: While what you want to do can be done with six separate arrays (I'm saying that even without realising what it is that you want to do), it would be better if you created a class with the six properties and have *one* `List<ThatClass>`.

Comment: if i understand you correcly, you can use [LINQ-Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2) to "query " items in the array

Comment: Your edits are not making it better. You have shown that you know how to address each of the lists, because you are adding values to each of them from that code, and you have shown that you know what the values being added are (because you manage to be adding them). If you know how to refer to a particular array and to a particular value being added to that array, what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Lizard, do you want to know, if, for example, all values inside `NHSnumber` are valid integers?

Comment: Are you saying that once you've split the line and added to your lists you then want to do some if logic, which you've not yet displayed?

Comment: styx- Yes I need multiple checks for each part of the array. NHSnumber will need the length checking as well as valid integers. Gender will have 3 fields, either M,F, or U. What is the best way of coding this if an 'if' statement is wrong.

Comment: Based on your last comment will the line always contain all of the elements listed or can 1 potentially be missing? Will they also always be in the same order?

Comment: They will always have the same elements and will be in the same order. Any invalid elements will be flagged and have a reason why they are flagged. E.g "NHSnumber is too short"

Comment: @Lizard use [fluentvalidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your patient information always contains all the data listed as well as in the same order, I would map the split out data into an object, probably called Patient:

```
public class Patient
{
    public int NHSNumber {get; set;}
    public dateTime DateOfBirth {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string GivenName {get; set;}
    public GenderOptions Gender {get; set;}
}
```

Create the enum GenderOptions:

```
public enum GenderOptions
{
    M,
    F,
    U
}
```

Once you've got an object then validate it. You can do this in many ways but a simple method like:

```
public bool IsValidPatient(Patient patient)
{
    // setup guard clauses
    if(patient.NHSNumber < 10) return false;
    if(patient.DateOfBirth.Year < 1900) return false

    // more checks
}
```

Of course, if you want to display an error based on what went wrong then you can return some sort of status object rather than a bool, which contains a message field or something indicating the error. If these checks aren't specific to patients only then you might want to split them out into individual ones and group what you need into 1 method for validating a patient.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you are trying to read some input from a file line by line, split on some key (it looks like you're trying to use the word "Error" as your splitter, which seems odd), and then parse the content into useful data.  Correct?

If the file you are reading from has a known format that doesn't change, basically you just need to access the correct elements of your "parts" array and assign the values.  You are on the right track.  I would suggest that if you know what the data type for each part of your data source is, that you use the appropriate conversion instead of trying to parse it manually.

You can use `Integer.TryParse(string, out int)` to ensure that invalid data doesn't cause an unhandled exception, but that requires an extra step.

```
int nhsNum;
if(!Integer.TryParse(part[0], out nhsNum) {
    // handle invalid number values here.
}
// at this point nhsNum will have the correctly parsed integer value.
NHSNumber.add(nhsNum)
```

You would repeat this for each element in the "part" array.

You can use `DateTime.TryParse(String, out DateTime)` if the date format in the file matches the date format of your system.  However, to better handle globalization, if the file contains a pre-defined date format you can also use [DateTime.TryParseExact(String, String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact) and use the exact date format through the IFormatProvider.

One last note.  Your "dateOfBirth" should probably be a `List<DateTime>` instead of a `List<int>`

Comment: I would suggest that the response from @sr28 is a more complete answer than mine.  Using an object to encapsulate all relevant data, rather than using multiple arrays is always a better approach.